# How do I play the Eets level pack?

Tags: eets

I got Eets on Steam, but I got a non-Steam download of a level pack for the game.

I unzipped the folder just to my downloads folder, but the levels won't play. I assume there is some spot that I need to put the folder - problem is, I have no clue where that might be.

Anyone know what I need to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in your steamapps\common directory for an "eets" directory or something similar.

The path is probably:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\eets\
```

However, it might vary depending on where Steam is installed and what version of Windows you're running.

There's likely a "levels" folder in there with a bunch of .eet files.  I think installing extra levels is just a matter of adding the new levels to this existing collection.

Comment: That appears to have worked. :)